# HTML cache manifest and dynamically loaded images

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, caching

I have a web app with offline functionality.
I managed to get the manifest working properly with all the required assets; css, js and images.

However I use angular to get from the server a list of user generated images, in a similar manner:

```
$scope.images = angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem('images')) || []

$http
.get('/my-rest-endpoint')
.then(function(res){
    $scope.images = res.data
    localStorage.setItem('images', angular.toJson(res.data))
}).catch()
```

I use the localStorage to keep the list even if the user is offline,
however I would like to have these pictures included in my offline cache...
Any idea how to achieve this?

BONUS:

In the future there may also be video files. What to do in that case?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many offline challenges. Your options are:

**1) Add images paths to manifest.appcache**:

Dynamically generate your `manifest.appcache`, inserting references to the images you want to offline. You could use the [appcache-nanny](https://github.com/gr2m/appcache-nanny) to check for updates.

**2) Store images in localStorage**:

This might be okay for a few images, but keep in mind localStorage capacity ranges from 2.5mb to 10mb depending on the device/browser, so that rules out video.

**3) Use localForage with offline-fetch**:

[localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) is a wrapper around IndexedDB/WebSQL that could give you up to 50mb client-side storage. [offline-fetch](https://github.com/john-doherty/offline-fetch) is a wrapper around [fetch](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch) *(the XMLHttpRequest replacement)*.

If you request your images using `offline-fetch` configured to use `localForage`, it will take care of serving them from disk when it detects the app is offline **but** would mean loading your images via JS and not img `src` attribute.

Comment: How do I generate manifest.appcache dynamically? I want to cache ajax response which contains image paths in array and I don't know the file names. I want to cache em all anyway. How do I generate manifest.appcache dynamically?

Comment: appcache manifest should only be used for static resources required to load the shell of the app. I created [offlineFetch](https://github.com/john-doherty/offline-fetch) to cache ajax requests, which meant all my app had to do was request resources using this wrapper and it would take care of the rest